# How to generate file descriptor in random forest example?

Tags: macos, hadoop, mahout

while trying to run random forest example I got the following error -

> hadoop jar mahout-core-0.9-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe –p testdata/KDDTrain+.arff –f testdata/KDDTrain+.info -d N 3 C 2 N C 4 N C 8 N 2 C 19 N L
>   I encounter the following error:
>   WARN tools.Describe: org.apache.commons.cli2.OptionException: Unexpected ?p while processing Options
>   Usage:
>    [--path  --file  --descriptor  [ ...]
>   --regression --help]
>   Options
>     --path (-p) path                                 Data path
>     --file (-f) file                                 Path to generated descriptor 
>                                                      file
>     --descriptor (-d) descriptor [descriptor ...]    data descriptor
>     --regression (-r)                                Regression Problem
>     --help (-h)                                      Print out help

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
that is typo mistake. its -p in your command.but it look something different(i think you paste it in command prompt)

command like this:

     hadoop jar /usr/lib/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-cdh4.6.0-job.jar org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.Describe -p /user/root/mahout/rinput.csv -f /user/root/mahout/rinput.info -d I 9 N L
```

just put - before p